# rbind rows that contain a "double" and a "charater"

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I am trying to import several excel sheets that all have the same column headers into one large data frame. I can import all the files with this code but when it come to the bind_rows it fails.

when I run the code I get this error:

> Error: Can't combine `..1$mxtotpr`  < double > and `..37$mxtotpr` < character> .

```
df <- list.files(full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  lapply(read_excel) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

My mxtotpr column contains a lot of empty rows due to missing data is this causing the issue?

How can I combine all the files into a large dataframe?

Comment: Check your data (we can't see from here), at least one of your spreadsheets is different from the others. Perhaps you need to use `read_excel(..., col_types=...)` to express that that column (perhaps others) must always be `character` (or whatever you expect it should be).

Comment: I would recommend checking the specific file (ending with "37"). load it separately and check for any values in "mxtotpr" that are atypical. If you locate the problem, change it to fit the others before rbind call.

Comment: Thank you! as recommended I went and checked the file ending in "37" and it had an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your columns are different formats, example:

```
df1=data.frame(A=c('a','b'),B=c(1/2,1/3))
df2=data.frame(A=c('c','d'),B=c('e','f'))
bind_rows(df1,df2)
```

> Error: Can't combine `..1$B`  and `..2$B` .

One workaround is to cast the problematic column as a character, e.g.:

```
df1a = data.frame(A=c('a','b'), B=as.character(c(1/2,1/3)))
df_combined = bind_rows(df1a,df2)
```

Result:

```
df_combined

  A                 B
1 a               0.5
2 b 0.333333333333333
3 c                 e
4 d                 f
```

However, as @Bloxx suggests, you're probably better off understanding what the data looks like and what's happening with your data import via the `read_excel()` function.